# Access confluence page using Rest API Queries

Tags: python, confluence, confluence-rest-api

how to authenticate to confluence page using python script. 
I need to login to confluence page using python script, and export a page to zip/csv.

Answer (score 1):

For authentication I used a simple GET request (using the requests library) to Confluence using the username and PW the user's provided.

if statuscode == 200 then success, anything else is likely a failure (although I believe 401 is specifically the authentication fail

It would be something like below:

```
import requests
urllogin = 'https://confluence.yourDomain.com/rest/api/content/'
login = requests.get(urllogin, auth=('username', 'password'))
if login.status_code == 200:
    print("Success")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind and prefer a simplified Confluence REST API client in Python, you might want to give [atlassian-python-api](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html) a chance. See [examples](https://pypi.org/project/atlassian-python-api/).